# Disk filter driver on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, device-driver

We are using Disk filter driver developed for Windows 8 OS.
Please let me know whether it is possible to use same driver on Windows 8 Phone OS.

Please let me know the forum, if this forum is not the right place to discuss Windows 8 Phone drivers.

Thanks,
Raphel

Answer (score 0):

No you can not use the same driver on windows phone (windows 8).
you have to develop the same driver from scratch by following Windows CE and Mobile Driver development for windows phone 7 that might work on windows 8.but ddk is not open for all better ask msdn support for the same.

Comment: Windows Phone 8 does not derive from Windows CE, rather shares the same Kernel as Windows 8. In saying that, I don't believe you could install a disk filter driver on Windows Phone 8. I don't believe you are given that level of access. In fact, AFAIK drivers can only be installed by OEMs as part of the ROM development process.